# How to place the values of an XML in a list?

Tags: python, xml, list

I have an XML file which looks like below, I'm trying to get all the 'headers' that contain a value in a simple list.

```
xml1 = '''
    <Record>
        <RecordID>London01</RecordID>
        <Location>London</Location>
        <Date>07-09-2020</Date>
        <Time>08u53m45s</Time>
        <Version>2.0.1</Version>
        <Version_2>v1.9</Version_2>
    <Max_30e>
        <I_25Hz_1s>56.40</I_25Hz_1s>
        <I_25Hz_2s>7.44</I_25Hz_2s>
    </Max_30e>
    <Max_50e>
        <I_75Hz_1s>1.56</I_75Hz_1s>
        <I_75Hz_2s>0.36</I_75Hz_2s>
    </Max_50e>
    <Sample>
        <Vehicleid>5664</Vehicleid>
        <NumberY>2742</NumberY>
        <NumberX>SNG</NumberX>
        <NumberZ>NSR</NumberZ>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
        <Vehicleid>1664</Vehicleid>
        <NumberY>4201</NumberY>
        <NumberX>ICM</NumberX>
        <NumberZ>NSR</NumberZ>
    </Sample>
</Record>'''
```

**This is what I tried:**

```
root = ET.fromstring(xml1)
values = []
for child in root:
    values.append(child.tag)
    for child1 in child:
        values.append(child1.tag)

print(values)
```

**This is my current output:**

```
['RecordID', 'Location', 'Date', 'Time', 'Version', 
'Version_2', 'Max_30e', 'I_25Hz_1s', 'I_25Hz_2s', 'Max_50e', 
'I_75Hz_1s', 'I_75Hz_2s', 'Sample', 'Vehicleid', 'NumberY', 
'NumberX', 'NumberZ', 'Sample', 'Vehicleid', 'NumberY', 
'NumberX', 'NumberZ']
```

**This is my desired output:**

```
['RecordID', 'Location', 'Date', 'Time', 'Version', 
'Version_2', 'I_25Hz_1s', 'I_25Hz_2s',  'I_75Hz_1s', 'I_75Hz_2s', 
'Vehicleid', 'NumberY', 'NumberX', 'NumberZ', 'Vehicleid', 
'NumberY', 'NumberX', 'NumberZ']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a flag

```
for child in root:
    has_child=False
    for child1 in child:
        has_child=True
        values.append(child1.tag)
    if not has_child:
        values.append(child.tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just going two levels deep then this should be fine. Going deeper would require recursion. The reason you're seeing them attached to your values is because there is a whitespace in the header text fields.

```
values = []
for child in root:
    if child.text.strip():
        values.append(child.tag)
    # Check for children
    for grandChild in child:
        if grandChild.text.strip():
            values.append(grandChild.tag)

print (values)
```